# Docker - failed to connect to running image

Tags: node.js, docker, centos6, dockerfile

Before I start explaining my error, let me say I'm a Windows user and don't have a lot of experience using Unix commands. So each of these steps are done using the **Docker Quickstart Terminal** (MINGW64).

It was a few weeks ago I first heard about docker and thought using it for a node/express website. So I installed the Docker package on my Synology server.

After finishing up the website I've done the following:

1. I followed the instructions on this website:
   https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/ Up until the last step,
   everything worked (including `docker run hello-world`)

---

2. Then it was onto **"Dockerizing a Node.js web app"**:
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/nodejs_web_app/

File hierarchy:

> src (C:.....\projectname)
>
> --assets (folder)
>
> --controllers (folder)
>
> --public (folder)
>
> --src (folder)
>
> --util (folder)
>
> --views (folder)
>
> --node_modules (folder)
>
> --bin (folder)
>
> ----www (file, no extention)
>
> --app.js (file)
>
> --Dockerfile (file, no extention)
>
> --package.json (file)

As for content:
**www**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('projectname:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(require('./controllers'));

};

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "bookshelf": "^0.9.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "i18n": "^0.8.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "knex": "^0.10.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.3",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.4",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

So as you can see in the package.json and www (which was generated by the express generator command), I have to write `npm start` to run the node/express server.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y nodejs npm

COPY package.json /projectname/package.json
RUN cd /projectname; npm install --production

COPY . /projectname

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

3. After a successful build `docker build -t username/projectname .` I do get a **SECURITY WARNING**:

   > Successfully built 5ed562273b56
   >
   > SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

Apart from that no errors are thrown, so I ran the image: `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d username/projectname`. After which I get a long hash string

> de297db51ab6fb3f842abb58267c1e189d2b9de51715a619a2f5431e868dc54f

---

4. Still following the principles on https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/nodejs_web_app/. To test the image I listed the **container id** using `docker ps` which got me this:

> CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | CREATED | STATUS | PORTS | NAMES

So completely empty! Nothing, except for the headers of the table... But when I use the code provided in the link and build their image it does give me a result (as stated in the article):

> CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | CREATED | STATUS | PORTS | NAMES
>
> 26d3ac309d81 | username/centos-node-testing | "node /src/index.js" | 35 minutes ago | Up 35 minutes | 0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp | gigantic_ritchie

---

5. Just to be sure, I tried calling the app using the **curl-command**: `curl -i 192.168.99.100:49160`. Unfortunately that gave me an error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 49160: Connection refused

The ip address is retrieved using the `docker-machine ip` command.

---

6. As a last resort, someone suggested to simply run the app using following command `docker run username/projectname`. That however gave me an error:

   > npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/package.json'
   >
   > npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
   >
   > npm ERR!     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
   >
   > npm ERR! or email it to:
   >
   > npm ERR!
   >
   > npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
   >
   > npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
   >
   > npm ERR! cwd /
   >
   > npm ERR! node -v v0.10.42
   >
   > npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
   >
   > npm ERR! path /package.json
   >
   > npm ERR! code ENOENT
   >
   > npm ERR! errno 34
   >
   > npm ERR!
   >
   > npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   >
   > npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
   >
   > npm ERR! not ok code 0

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container is non-existent because the command you've provided (`CMD`, above) is returning a non-zero exit status, and the container is destroyed due to failure. In your Dockerfile, let's please try something like the following, which should ensure that `npm start` is run from within your project root:

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y nodejs npm

COPY package.json /projectname/package.json

# Set the working directory 
WORKDIR /projectname

RUN npm install --production

COPY . /projectname

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Also, for future, you might have luck troubleshooting a container if you use `docker run -it username/projectname /bin/bash`.

Comment: Amazing, it works!!!! I just had to change the Node/express port to 8080 too and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: Also worth noting here: If you've run `npm install` from within the project root outside the container, the `COPY . /projectname` would overwrite the `./node_modules` generated by the container build. I've done this to myself before, so I thought I'd mention it :)